# twitter embed timeline no longer works as of today?

Tags: twitter

Hi I am receiving the following error (on all my sites) when the site attempts to embed a twitter account timeline. I looked at the status page https://api.twitterstat.us/ and it makes no mention of any problems with twitter...

https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/timeline/profile?callback=__twttr.callbacks.tl_i0_profile_ingentaconnect_old&dnt=false&domain=ic.ox-dev-01.ingenta.com%3A9151&lang=en&screen_name=ingentaconnect&suppress_response_codes=true&t=1829998&tz=GMT%2B0000&with_replies=false net::ERR_ABORTED 404
fetch @ widgets.js:8

Here is the embed code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="340" href="https://twitter.com/ingentaconnect?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by ingentaconnect</a> 
                            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Note I'm based in UK if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me perfectly.

A workaround is to get https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js; in its code, change https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com to https://syndication.twimg.com, store within your website and when embedding Twitter timeline, use your modified version instead of https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.

Here is the link on twitter where the discussion was done:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-timeline-does-not-show/168085/10

Comment: I think this answer might be outdated now. I couldn't find "https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com" in https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.